# dcast keeping four value variables and two factors

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I have a *data.frame* in R in long format, and I want to cast it into wide.
It has monthly data from several clients, and I want the final *data.frame* to have the mean per client of `he`, `vo`, `ep` and `fe`.
`store` and `pr` should be fixed for each client.
I think `dcast` from package `reshape2` should do the job, but I can't make it work.

```
month   store   client  he  vo  ep  fe  pr
jan 1   54010   12  392 1   7   Basic
jan 2   54011   12  376 2   2   Premium
jan 1   54012   11  385 2   6   Basic
feb 1   54010   10  394 3   7   Basic
feb 2   54011   10  385 1   1   Premium
feb 1   54012   11  395 1   1   Basic
mar 1   54010   11  416 2   2   Basic
mar 2   54011   11  417 3   4   Premium
mar 1   54012   11  390 0   2   Basic
apr 1   54010   11  389 2   NA  Basic
apr 2   54011   7   398 6   3   Premium
apr 1   54012   11  368 1   3   Basic
```

Comment: You don't have any information about years so how do you want to calculate an annual mean? Or is all your data only from a single year and you just want the mean per client?

Comment: FYI, with base R you could do: `aggregate(cbind(he, vo, ep, fe) ~ client, dat, mean)` to achieve the same result as in hrbrmstr's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need annual mean of those columns by client (it wasn't clear), `dplyr` can do it:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- read.table(text="month   store   client  he  vo  ep  fe  pr
jan 1   54010   12  392 1   7   Basic
jan 2   54011   12  376 2   2   Premium
jan 1   54012   11  385 2   6   Basic
feb 1   54010   10  394 3   7   Basic
feb 2   54011   10  385 1   1   Premium
feb 1   54012   11  395 1   1   Basic
mar 1   54010   11  416 2   2   Basic
mar 2   54011   11  417 3   4   Premium
mar 1   54012   11  390 0   2   Basic
apr 1   54010   11  389 2   NA  Basic
apr 2   54011   7   398 6   3   Premium
apr 1   54012   11  368 1   3   Basic", stringsAs=F, header=T)

mt <- function(x, ...) { mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) }

dat %>%
  group_by(client) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mt), -store, -pr, -month)

## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
## 
##   client he     vo ep       fe
## 1  54010 11 397.75  2 5.333333
## 2  54011 10 394.00  3 2.500000
## 3  54012 11 384.50  1 3.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a data table solution using the `dat` data from @hrbrmstr's answer:

```
library(data.table)
## coerce to data table
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
## run mean() on columns 4 through 7, grouped by 'client'
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = 4:7, by = client]
#    client he     vo ep       fe
# 1:  54010 11 397.75  2 5.333333
# 2:  54011 10 394.00  3 2.500000
# 3:  54012 11 384.50  1 3.000000
```